# Import configuration files in haproxy.cfg

Tags: haproxy

I have almost 200 lines of ACL configurations in `haprox.cfg` and also contains 150 backends. 
To remove this configuration complexity, I want to bundle this configuration in separate files and will import those files in `haprox.cfg`.
Is this possible in haproxy?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know HAproxy does not have anything similar to apache's [`Include & IncludeOptional`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#include) directives.

There is no native support for multiple configuration files other than starting HAproxy with repeated `-f <config-file>` command line switches. [see this thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.haproxy/5888).

You can script something though to merge multiple subsections into a larger file similar to [this approach](http://lazic.info/josip/post/splitting-haproxy-config/) although I would probably go the route and modify the [init script](http://www.haproxy.org/download/contrib/haproxy.init.el5) to append additional configuration files automatically (untested):

```sh
# Load additional configuration snippets from /etc/haproxy.d/*.cfg
OPTIONS=""
for file in /etc/haproxy.d/*.cfg ; do test -f $file && OPTIONS="$OPTIONS -f $file" ; done

start() {
  /usr/sbin/$BASENAME -c -q -f /etc/$BASENAME/$BASENAME.cfg $OPTIONS
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Errors found in configuration file, check it with '$BASENAME check'."
    return 1
  fi

  echo -n "Starting $BASENAME: "
  daemon /usr/sbin/$BASENAME -D -f /etc/$BASENAME/$BASENAME.cfg $OPTIONS -p /var/run/$BASENAME.pid
  RETVAL=$?
  echo
  [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch /var/lock/subsys/$BASENAME
  return $RETVAL
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I see the version 1.7.5-2 2017/05/17 has the following help:

```
       -f <configuration file|dir>
              Specify  configuration  file or directory path. If the argument is a directory the files (and only files) it contains
              are added in lexical order (using LC_COLLATE=C) ; only non hidden files with ".cfg" extension are added.
```

So in my case editing `/etc/default/haproxy` so that it contains

```
CONFIG="/etc/haproxy/"
```

enables me to put more .cfg files in `/etc/haproxy` and all is read and configured.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this simple step.

1. Insert one line script (`cat /etc/$BASENAME/conf.d/*.cfg > $CFG`) in `/etc/init.d/haproxy`
   Here is position where you must insert line
   `CFG=/etc/$BASENAME/$BASENAME.cfg
    cat /etc/$BASENAME/conf.d/*.cfg > $CFG
    [ -f $CFG ] || exit 1`
2. Reload daemon config with `systemctl daemon-reload`
3. Make directory `mkdir /etc/haproxy/conf.d`
4. Move default haproxy.cfg to conf.d as global.cfg `mv /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg /etc/haproxy/conf.d/global.cfg`
5. Create your other .cfg file in conf.d directory
6. Just restart your haproxy service `systemctl restart haproxy`
7. NOTE: `/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg` will be automaticly created from all files in conf.d/